# when i am debug using gdb compiler ,can't able see the printed values in console window

Tags: sphinx

I've downloaded the sphinx-2.2.5-release version ,installed it successfully...

steps::

./configure --prefix=/home/syscon/Documents/work/sphinx-2.2.5-release --with-debug

sudo make clean

sudo make

sudo make install

mysql -u root -p** tests -e "select * from tests.documents"

mysql -u root -p** tests < example.sql

sudo ./src/indexer --all

To debug the searchd in console,

sudo gdb -tui --args ./src/searchd --console

Once this step has been done,it goes inside the console window,

> break SendSearchResponse
>
> run

```
void SendSearchResponse ( SearchHandler_c & tHandler, InputBuffer_c & tReq, int iSock,
int iVer, int iMasterVer )
{
                ....
                ....
                // serve the response
                NetOutputBuffer_c tOut ( iSock );

                int iReplyLen = 0;
                bool bAgentMode = ( iMasterVer>0 );

                cout<< "Length" << endl;
                cout << iReplyLen << endl;
}
```

i tried printing the statements inside the function,while debugging,it crosses that
      printf statements but its not printing anything in the console window.

what shall i need to do inorder to print the statements in console window?

will i need to enable any thing in sphinx.conf?

Comment: why yet another profile? http://stackoverflow.com/users/4204665/udaya-chandran

Comment: Tat profile was blocked

Comment: Hmm http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th